# Passing Information To A Class On Initialisation

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I'm struggling to understand how class initialisation works.  From looking at solutions to other problems I have this as an example of the classes in my app.

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit

class Ground : SKSpriteNode {

override init(texture: SKTexture!, color: SKColor, size: CGSize) {

    super.init(texture: texture, color: color, size: size)

    self.zPosition = -20
    self.name = "Ground";

}

func configure (size: CGSize, position: CGPoint) {
    self.size = size
    self.position = position
    // Set up the Physics
    self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: size)
    self.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Player
    self.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Ground
    self.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.All
    self.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    self.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
    self.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
    self.physicsBody?.mass = 1.99999
}

convenience init(color: SKColor, isActive: Bool = false) {
    let size = CGSize(width: 10, height: 10);
    self.init(texture:nil, color: color, size: size)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    // Decoding length here would be nice...
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
}
```

I've put the 'configure' function as a kludge fix to let me pass the scene to the class so I can set sizes depending on the size of the device screen.  Ideally I would like to just pull this information on initialisation but everything I try throws up errors that I don't understand.

Im not sure which way would be correct but I was wondering firstly, how would I pass arguments to the class to start with.. e.g..

```
let myClass = Ground(scene: self)
```

or can I somehow pull the scene information from directly within the class?  I can pass info into functions/methods as I did with 'configure' but I couldn't get it to work on initialisation which would certainly be cleaner.

How would you guys do it?

Answer (score 1):

### Size

You should not programmatically change the size of a sprite depending on the current device, just use the same size and then let SpriteKit resizing it for you.

### Loading from .sks

This initializer

```
init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
```

is used when the Sprite is loaded from a .sks file. However in Xcode 7 you cannot pass values from the .sks to the sprite to set the attributes. I'm not sure you are using a .sks file so for now I am just throwing a `fatal_error` here. In Xcode 8 however you will be able to pass values from the .sks file to your own class.

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("Not implemented")
}
```

### Scene

You don't need to pass a reference of the current scene to your class. Every `SKNode` has the `scene` property, just use it to retrieve the scene where the node lives. Of course keep in mind that if you invoke `.scene` **before** the node has been added to a scene it will returns `nil`.

### Code

This is the final code

```
class Ground : SKSpriteNode {

    init(color: SKColor = .clearColor(), isActive:Bool = false) {
        let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "ground")
        super.init(texture: texture, color: color, size: texture.size())
        self.name = "Ground"
        self.zPosition = -20

        let physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: texture, size: texture.size())
        physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Player
        physicsBody.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Ground
        physicsBody.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.All
        physicsBody.affectedByGravity = false
        physicsBody.allowsRotation = false
        physicsBody.dynamic = false
        physicsBody.mass = 1.99999
        self.physicsBody = physicsBody
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("Not implemented")
    }
}
```

Comment: How does this work: "In Xcode 8 however you will be able to pass values from the .sks file to your own class." This might be my comprehension problems, but I don't see how a .sks file can pass anything, ever.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something else you're trying to do, you should be able to move the initialization of the PhysicsBody and the other properties from you configure() method and into your init() for the class. Then you can pre-size the texture you pass in on instantiation to result in the proper size for the device.

Also, the position property of the SKSpriteNode can be set by the instantiating class. This means you can accomplish the sizing based on device and the setting of the position property right after instantiating it in your scene and before adding it as a child of the scene.

ADDED:

```
class Ground : SKSpriteNode {

override init(texture: SKTexture!, color: SKColor, size: CGSize) {
    super.init(texture: texture, color: color, size: size)

}



convenience init(texture: String, scene: SKScene, isActive: Bool = false) {
    let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "\(yourtexturename)")
    self.init(texture:teture, color: color, size: scene.size)
    self.size = size
    self.position = [YOU CAN NOW SET POSITION BASED ON THE SCENE] 
    self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: size)
    self.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Player
    self.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Ground
    self.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.All
    self.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    self.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
    self.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
    self.physicsBody?.mass = 1.99999

    self.zPosition = -20
    self.name = "Ground";
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    // Decoding length here would be nice...
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
```

}

You might not need to override the original init() method but I didn't test anything.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply.  how would I do that?  when I try I get all kinds of errors about super.init and the like.  I can't find an example of a class that uses the scene dimensions for positioning and sizing the sprite.  I know I'm being thick but having init, super.init and convenience init is really confusing me.

Comment: Im trying to keep all the class specific configuration in the class itself rather than defining it in GameScene when it doesn't need to be.  From what I do understand about classes is they are supposed to self contained and self managed as much as possible?

Comment: The reason you have to override the init() method in your class is that it is a required initializer and it needs to have each of those properties passed to it on initialization. The required initializer must also call the required init of the super class. A convenience initializer is one you write to make your "init-ing" simpler by providing hard-coded properties.

Comment: In other words, if you want that self-contained nature of this particular SpriteNode you can write your convenience initializer with the name of your ground texture as a string, you can pass a reference to the scene, and then grab all of the information you want from inside that initializer. I will provide a code example in the next answer.

Comment: Just tried the code example you gave and it doesn't seem to be using the convenience initializer.  Just for clarity, I forgot to mention this particular class doesn't have a texture and its hidden behind a background sprite.  Its just used for the physics body to create an invisible ground on the screen.  Just for testing though, I put a texture in and configured the size of the object based on the scene but it doesn't get set and if I print the scene dimensions, it doesn't show anything in the log making me assume its not being run.

Comment: Tried both answers and feel I've not explained very well what this particular class is doing.  Im sorry for that.  It basically has no texture and is used for the physics body.  Its the width of the screen and positioned low down on the screen using (frame.height / 100) * 5. its height is 10% of the screen.   I realise the class I put up mentions texture and color.  They were in the class example I used and when I tried to remove them it threw up errors.  Im hoping if I get a working example of this, I can apply it to other classes I've got that DO use textures though.

Comment: @CraigArmitage have gotten much further in understanding how initialisation and passing in it works? I haven't and am wondering if you've gleaned some insights and wisdom. I have knowledge (a little) with zero understanding.